# Datatable Pivot with Multiple Data Values In Same Row

Tags: c#, datatable, pivot, pivot-table

I'm trying to pivot my datatable but I don't have much experience with pivots so I hope I'm explaining it correctly. I'm using this article that seems to be very popular for this: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/46486/Pivoting-DataTable-Simplified

My Data looks like:

```
school  | class  | students  | teachers  
.............................................................  
school1 | class1 | students1 | teachers1  
school1 | class2 | students2 | teachers2  
school1 | class3 | students3 | teachers3
```

Right now my pivot looks like I have

```
school  | class1    | class2    | class3  
.............................................................  
school1 | students1 | students2 | students3
```

And that's fine. But How can I extend the examples in the article to include BOTH students and teachers in each class? So the desired result is something like

```
school  | class1 | class2  | class3  
.............................................................  
school1 | students1 | teachers1 | students2 | teachers2 | students3 | teachers3
```

Comment: The final desired result is not clear, do you want the `students1` and `teachers1` to be concatenated into a single column under `class1`, etc?

Comment: @bluefeet Sorry, that wasn't clear. I can see how I can concatenate them on my own. I'm preferring for them to be separate columns. I'm assuming this can be done but I might be wrong on that.

Comment: @JimBeam What database are you using?  Do you want this to be done using SQL or C#?